# Firmware will not update

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, permissions, 15.04, firmware

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-firmware
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/24.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 322 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 233907 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-firmware_1.143.6_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware (1.143.6) over (1.143.3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.143.6_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create `/lib/firmware/brcm/bcm4329-fullmac-4.bin.dpkg-new' (while processing `./lib/firmware/brcm/bcm4329-fullmac-4.bin'): Permission denied
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.143.6_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`stat /lib/firmware/brcm`

```
  File: ‘/lib/firmware/brcm’
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 807h/2055d  Inode: 1310841     Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2015-04-22 05:06:10.000000000 -0700
Modify: 2015-10-08 22:21:45.910890160 -0700
Change: 2015-10-17 12:56:21.076474727 -0700
 Birth: -
```

`apt-cache policy linux-firmware`

```
linux-firmware:
  Installed: 1.143.3
  Candidate: 1.143.6
  Version table:
     1.143.6 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-proposed/main amd64 Packages
     1.143.4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.143.3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.143 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

`tree -pufid /lib | grep '/lib/firmware'`

```
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/3.19.0-31-generic
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/3.19.0-31-generic/3com
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/3.19.0-31-generic/bnx2
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/3.19.0-31-generic/bnx2x
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/3.19.0-31-generic/e100
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/3.19.0-31-generic/emi26
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/3.19.0-31-generic/emi62
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/3.19.0-31-generic/korg
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/3.19.0-31-generic/qlogic
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/3.19.0-31-generic/tigon
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/3.19.0-32-generic
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/3.19.0-32-generic/3com
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/3.19.0-32-generic/bnx2
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/3.19.0-32-generic/bnx2x
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/3.19.0-32-generic/e100
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/3.19.0-32-generic/emi26
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/3.19.0-32-generic/emi62
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/3.19.0-32-generic/korg
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/3.19.0-32-generic/qlogic
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/3.19.0-32-generic/tigon
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/3com
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/acenic
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/adaptec
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/advansys
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/ar3k
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/asihpi
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/ath10k
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA988X
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/ath6k
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/ath6k/AR6003
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/ath6k/AR6003/hw2.0
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/ath6k/AR6003/hw2.1.1
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/ath6k/AR6004
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/ath6k/AR6004/hw1.2
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/ath6k/AR6004/hw1.3
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/av7110
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/bnx2x
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/brcm
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/carl9170fw
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/carl9170fw/carlfw
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/carl9170fw/carlfw/include
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/carl9170fw/carlfw/src
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/carl9170fw/carlfw/usb
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/carl9170fw/config
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/carl9170fw/extra
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/carl9170fw/include
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/carl9170fw/include/linux
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/carl9170fw/include/shared
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/carl9170fw/minifw
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/carl9170fw/toolchain
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/carl9170fw/tools
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/carl9170fw/tools/carlu
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/carl9170fw/tools/carlu/src
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/carl9170fw/tools/include
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/carl9170fw/tools/lib
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/carl9170fw/tools/src
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/cis
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/cis/src
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/cpia2
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/cxgb3
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/cxgb4
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/dsp56k
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/ea
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/edgeport
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/emi26
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/emi62
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/ene-ub6250
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/ess
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/go7007
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/hp
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/i915
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/intel
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/intel-ucode
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/isci
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/kaweth
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/keyspan
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/keyspan_pda
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/korg
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/libertas
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/matrox
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/moxa
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/mrvl
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/mwl8k
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/ositech
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/r128
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/radeon
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/RTL8192E
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/rtl_nic
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/rtlwifi
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/sb16
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/scripts
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/slicoss
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/sun
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/tehuti
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/ti-connectivity
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/tigon
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/ttusb-budget
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/ueagle-atm
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/usbdux
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/vicam
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/vxge
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/yam
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/yamaha
[drwxr-xr-x root    ]  /lib/firmware/zd1211
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of `tree -pufid /lib | grep '/lib/firmware'`